# SQL Server converting varbinary to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, varbinary

I want to do conversion in T-SQL from a `varbinary` type to string type

Here is an example :

First I got this `varbinary`

```
0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3
```

And then I want to convert it to

```
21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
```

How to do this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have? Andras's answer only works on 2008 or higher, for example.

Comment: That's true, I updated my answer, so if you have older version you need a different solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [varbinary to string on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @varbinaryField varbinary(max);
SET @varbinaryField = 0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3;

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max),@varbinaryField,2), 
@varbinaryField
```

UPDATED:
For SQL Server 2008

Comment: It can also be used when retrieving directly from a table:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), MyBinaryField, 2) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 123456`

Comment: If you wish to preserve the '0x' prefix, use the 1 style Flag in the CONVERT expression (instead of 2). `SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX), MyBinaryField, 1) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 123456;`.

Comment: And how check it for null inline?
`DECLARE @varbinaryField varbinary(max);
SET @varbinaryField = 0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3;

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), ISNULL(@varbinaryField, 'value is NULL'), 2), 
@varbinaryField` raise error `Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but here is an alternative approach that I have found more useful in some situations. I believe the master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr function has been available in SQL Server at least since SQL2K. Adding it here just for completeness.  Some readers may also find it instructive to look at the source code of this function.

```
declare @source varbinary(max);
set @source = 0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3;
select varbin_source = @source
,string_result = master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (@source)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert a single `VARBINARY` value into `VARCHAR` (`STRING`) you can do by declaring a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @var VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @var = 0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3
SELECT CAST(@var AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

If you are trying to select from table column then you can do like this:

```
SELECT CAST(myBinaryCol AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM myTable
```

Comment: For some reason on SQL Server 2012, Converting didnt work, but Cast did the trick??? Thanks!

Comment: Simple CAST may not work by default because the hex expression is converted to ASCII/UNICODE. Use CONVERT with a style flag (1 or 2).

Answer (score 3):

This works in both SQL 2005 and 2008:

```
declare @source varbinary(max);
set @source = 0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3;
select cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)');
```

Comment: How to do the same convert for field but not for variable?

Comment: To do the same but for a column rather than a variable, you would use the sql:column function (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx). So it would be cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("someColumnNameHere"))'

Answer (score 2):

I looked everywhere for an answer and finally this worked for me:

```
SELECT Lower(Substring(MASTER.dbo.Fn_varbintohexstr(0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3), 3, 8000))
```

Outputs to (string):

> 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3

You can use it in your WHERE or JOIN conditions as well in case you want to compare/match varbinary records with strings

Comment: Any idea on how to update that field back with the string re-converted back to varbinary?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example I wrote to convert and convert back using the 2 convert methods, I also checked it with a fixed string

declare @VB1 VARBINARY(500),@VB2 VARBINARY(500),@VB3 VARBINARY(500)

declare @S1 VARCHAR(500)

SET @VB1=HASHBYTES('SHA1','Test')

SET @S1=CONVERT(varchar(500),@VB1,2)

SET @VB2=CONVERT(varbinary(500),@S1,2)

SET @VB3=CONVERT(varbinary(500),'640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA',2)

SELECT @VB1,@S1,@VB2,@VB3

IF @VB1=@VB2 PRINT 'They Match(2)'

IF @VB1=@VB3 PRINT 'They Match(3)'

PRINT str(Len(@VB1))

PRINT str(Len(@S1))

PRINT str(Len(@VB2))

SET @VB1=HASHBYTES('SHA1','Test')

SET @S1=CONVERT(varchar(500),@VB1,1)

SET @VB2=CONVERT(varbinary(500),@S1,1)

SELECT @VB1,@S1,@VB2

IF @VB1=@VB2 PRINT 'They Match(1)'

PRINT str(Len(@VB1))

PRINT str(Len(@S1))

PRINT str(Len(@VB2))

and the output

|||
0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA|640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA|0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA|0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA

(1 row(s) affected)

They Match(2)

They Match(3)

```
    20
    40
    20
```

||
0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA|0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA|0x640AB2BAE07BEDC4C163F679A746F7AB7FB5D1FA

(1 row(s) affected)

They Match(1)

```
    20
    42
    20
```