# SQL Server compare varchar field with binary(16)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables - Table A with primary key column of type binary(16) and another table B with foreign key referring to the same column but with data type as varchar(50). So table A has values like  `0x0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A` and  table B has the same value stored as `0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A`.

How do i compare these 2 columns, which would give me

```
0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A = 0x0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server converting varbinary to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139073/sql-server-converting-varbinary-to-string)

Comment: added sql-server-2005 tag, which explains why [Paul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25244777/3241) did no work

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the binary(16) to a string.  A sample of how to do this can be found in the question below.  This question converts a varbinary to a string, but the same technique can be used for a binary column or variable:

[SQL Server converting varbinary to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139073/sql-server-converting-varbinary-to-string)

Example code for how to do this is below:

```
declare @bin binary(16), @str varchar(50)
set @bin = 0x0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A
set @str = '0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A'

select @bin as'binary(16)', @str as 'varchar(50)'

-- the binary value is not equal to the string value
-- this statement returns 'binary value is not equal to string'
if @bin = @str select 'binary value is equal to string'
else select 'binary value is not equal to string'

declare @binstr varchar(50)
select @binstr = convert(varchar(50), @bin, 2)
select @binstr

-- the converted string value matches the other string
-- the result of this statement is "converted string is equal"
if @binstr = @str select 'converted string is equal'
else select 'converted string is NOT equal'
```

To use this in a join, you can include the conversion in the `ON` clause of the inner join or in a `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from TableA
inner join TableB
    on TableB.char_fk = convert(varchar(50), TableA.bin_pk, 2)
```

**UPDATE**

For SQL Server 2005, you can use an XML approach [shown by Peter Larsson here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_larsson/archive/2010/01/27/convert-binary-value-to-string-value.aspx):

```
-- Prepare value
DECLARE @bin VARBINARY(MAX)
SET     @bin = 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8

-- Display the results
SELECT @bin AS OriginalValue,
        CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin"))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ConvertedString
```

You can also use the undocumented function `sys.fn_varbintohexstr`, but as [this post on dba.stackexchange.com explains](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46910/sys-fn-varbintohexstr-returns-null-if-varbinary-data-is-more-then-2000-as-datale), there are several reasons why you should avoid it.

Comment: This does not work, i need to convert either binary to varchar or vice versa to be abel to equate these 2 - 0x0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A and '0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A'

Comment: Those are the example values I used in my code above.  The code converts binary to varchar for comparison.  Did the code not work, or do you need something else?

Comment: I included a sample of how to do this conversion in a join.

Comment: It does not work, gives a different value. Found the answer on an older post though. need to use master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (@source)

Comment: I'm confused.  When I run this code, it gives me exactly the same value, and the second comparison returns "converted string is equal".

Comment: For me it is returning "converted string is NOT equal"

Comment: @patil.rahulk - you should have said that you are using sqlserver 2005. Paul's solution works fine from 2008 up

Comment: I updated my answer with a SQL 2005 solution using XML and a link to some reasons to avoid the undocumented function `sys.fn_varbintohexstr`.

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT` with style 2 to get a binary representation of the hexadecimal string;

```
... where TableA.bin_pk = CONVERT(VARBINARY, TableB.char_fk, 2)
```

Comment: CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0007914BFFEC4603A6900045492EFA1A', 2) gives 0x303030373931344246464543343630334136393030303435343932454641

Answer (score 0):

The correct aproach is to set both fields in the same datatype. in order to to do this create a new table say temp and use select into and convert:

```
select field1,...,convert(varchar(50),varbinary(16),fieldToConvert)...,fieldN

into myNewTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I need to use

```
master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (@source)
```

which converts a varbinary to varchar, and then works perfectly well for comparison in my scenario.