# Convert binary to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, binary, varchar

I need to change the binary output to varchar(string), but it must same as to be the binary output. But while converting the binary(hex) value to varchar, empty set will be returned. Kindly help me.

E.x

If this is my binary value `0x24000000008B0100000000`.

I need the same `0x24000000008B0100000000` output after converting it into string.

Comment: Same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139073/sql-server-converting-varbinary-to-string

Comment: @Prisoner But the 0x is trimmed from the output.I need the output include that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
declare @val binary(20)
set @val=0x24000000008B0100000000

select @val, CONVERT(varchar(max),@val,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

this also works for me :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), varbinary_val, 1);
```

just change your value with varbinary_val

Answer (score 0):

should work like:

```
DECLARE @a BINARY(20) = 0x24000000008B0100000000
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(max),@a,1), @a
```

Comment: But the 0x is trimmed from the output.I need the output include that

Comment: @SujithTee i updated my post. I just changed the third parameter of convert from 2 to 1