# Convert varbinary to string within query

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, varbinary

I am trying to query a table that contains some XML values in varbinary format and having difficulty getting meaningful output.

I have looked at several Google results and Stack Overflow answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server), but the answers suggested do not seem to work for me.

My latest version of the query is as follows:

```
select top 100 EntryDataAndTime, EntryType, RequestID, Sequence, ServerName,
       cast(XML as varchar(max)) as xml_string
  from RequestResponseLog
```

This returns the final column in a format like: `‹½U_oÓ0//¼ ¾ê+Zœ`...

I have also tried:

```
select top 100 EntryDataAndTime, EntryType, RequestID, Sequence, ServerName,
       Convert(varchar(8000), XML, 2) as xml_string
  from RequestResponseLog
```

which seems to return the final column in hex format e.g. `1F8B0800000000000400BD555F6FD330102F2FBC`...

Most of the Google results and the Stack Overflow question I referred to above include a step where you do something like...

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = 0x5468697320697320612074657374
```

before you use the cast function. I am not entirely clear what the 0x54.. value is, but this seems to assume that you only want to convert a single value rather than multiple rows as I am, unless I have misunderstood?

Any help to get the conversion to readable strings working within the query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to cast to `nvarchar(max)` or `xml`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson No luck with either of these, I get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out after investigating further than some compression had been done at the application level in C# before writing this data to the database as BLOBs. Because of this there are no standard SQL server functions to translate the data into human readable form, I would need to reverse the process that compressed the data in an application.

I have left this question here rather than deleting in-case anyone else has a similar issue in the future.