# Execute SQL query in Binary Form

Tags: t-sql

I have seen executing something like this in SQL Server

`EXEC (0x53454C45435420312041532054)`

or simply like

`0x53454C45435420312041532054`

Above binary form is equal to `SELECT 1 AS T`

But I don't remember the exact way how to do this.

Does anyone know executing query like this?

**Update:**

I know how to convert `Binary` into `Varchar` and `Varchar` into `Binary`. What I am asking here is how to execute the query in Binary Form?

This is one way,

```
Declare @q as nvarchar(1000) 
-- 0x530045004C004500430054002000310020004100530020005400 = SELECT 1 AS T
SET @q = CAST(0x530045004C004500430054002000310020004100530020005400 as nvarchar(1000));
EXEC (@q)
```

Any other way?

Comment: What is the magic number `0x53454C45435420312041532054`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan "Select 1 as T"

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I am pretty sure there is no other way to do this.
You cannot simply execute binary data.

You can use [exec](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/13/sql-server-difference-between-exec-and-execute-vs-exec-use-execexecute-for-sp-always/), as you already do, or you could use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), but both expect you to pass the query to be executed as a string (NVARCHAR).