# Retrieve compressed GZip info from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which stores the contents of a compressed GZip file. Not sure if the original information was XML or CSV or what. I don't have access to the original. The PulledContent column is varbinary and looks like this `0x1F8B08000000000004006553C18E9B3010BD57EA3F706C0F2B63...`

How can I convert this info into something readable by a human?

I thought the solution might be here: [varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server).

But when I try this: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), PulledContent, 2);`

It just gives me a slightly different string of numbers and letters like this `1F8B08000000000004006553C18E9B3010BD57EA3F70...`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The data you return from the "PulledContent" column is in binary GZip compressed format.  In order to transform this binary data into a human readable format you will need to perform the following tasks.

1) Uncompress the binary data using an appropriate library.  If you are in the windows environment you could use the .net class [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform this task.

2) Convert the binary data to a string. You can accomplish this by using the .net Encoding class.

```
string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I should also add that I do not have access to Visual Studio or any ability to install new programs. Severely limiting, I know. I was hoping there was a way using only SSMS.

Comment: @pteridoid You do not need Visual Studio or any new program. You have the csc.exe C# compiler already installed. You can compile SQLCLR assemblies and deploy them on the target system.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This question was asked and answered prior to SQL Server 2016 being released which introduced the [COMPRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql) and [DECOMPRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decompress-transact-sql) built-in functions (which merely expose the `Compress` / `Decompress` operations of the .NET `GZipStream` class). Try those first if you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer.

---

To uncompress the `VARBINARY` value in T-SQL (whether in SSMS or a SQL script, etc), you can use a SQLCLR function to do that translation via a simple `SELECT` statement. You would use the `GzipStream` class that @Doug mentioned.

But, if you don't want to write any code to get this functionality, it is available in the Free version of the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_31764905) SQLCLR library (which I am the author of, and again, this function is free). For example:

```sql
SELECT SQL#.Util_GUnzip(PulledContent)
FROM   SchemaName.TableName
WHERE  SomeField = something;
```

That will return a `VARBINARY` value as well, but it will be the uncompressed value. At that point, you can attempt to convert it to various forms to see what it really is. A binary file will still be binary, but plain text should come out as at least partially readable (fully readable if the collation is the proper encoding):

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SQL#.Util_GUnzip(PulledContent))
FROM   SchemaName.TableName
WHERE  SomeField = something;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SQL#.Util_GUnzip(PulledContent))
FROM   SchemaName.TableName
WHERE  SomeField = something;
```

Comment: Have not tested it, but this answer needs attention. We ran into a problem of saving huge data set in a column to validate everything we inserted for few months. I was planning to compress it before saving and make it readable when records are presented to the consumers. This could be very helpful.

Comment: @JamshaidK. Thanks. Please see the update that I just posted to the top of this answer regarding built-in functions that didn't exist when I first posted this answer. Those functions may be relevant depending on what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: I have gone through those functions. But it is still good to have a GZip utility plus, for the older version, this is still very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be much more complicated than this, using the most excellent [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/):

```
static byte[] FetchAndDeCompressData( int key )
{
  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your-connect-string-here") )
  using ( SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.fetch_gzipped_data" ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@key" , key ) ;
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
    return Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream.UncompressBuffer( bytes ) ;
  }
}
```

What you do with the `byte[]` of decompressed octets is dependent on what it is. If you know that it's text, you could simply run it through something like

```
Encoding.Default.GetString( bytes ) ;
```

But you'll need to know what the underlying encoding is.

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---