# Convert varbinary to string on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have been trying to convert a `vabinary` column to a string in SQL Server 2000. I have tried the recommended methods on this post: [varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server/35745411?noredirect=1#comment59177387_35745411) but not had any luck yet.

I have it working in SQL Server 2008, just not in SQL Server 2000.

My binary is

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C0FFFF000000000000
```

When I use select

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), @data, 0)
```

in SQL Server 2008 it works fine, but when I use it in SQL Server 2000 the output I get is

```
'ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ'
```

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: please remove mysql tag from your question

Comment: you can probably adopt master..fn_varbintohexsubstring to sql server 2000

Answer (score 0):

you can do it SQL Server 2005/2000 by using XML.

```
DECLARE @bin VARBINARY(MAX)
SET     @bin = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C0FFFF000000000000

SELECT @bin AS actualvalue,
        CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin"))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS StringValue
```

Comment: I don't think this code works on 2000. Aside from the use of `MAX` (but that's just used for the example here), it's also using the XML data type. Which was [New in SQL Server 2005](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170809(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: yes..i tested it in sql server 2005 but don't have the environment to test in 2000

Comment: Unfortuently this doesnt seem to work with 2000 either, I get: 37000 (170) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Line 5: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @Jeffrey Damien has detailed the reason why in [the comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936070/convert-varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server#comment59529210_35936152), XML data type wasn't introduced in SQL Server until SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Yeh I've had a look at that, no ideas how else I can do it?