# Sqlserver varbinary data want to select as varchar without truncation

Tags: sql-server, binary

I'm running the following to retrieve my converted binary data, I then save the output to a file and it is truncated !

```
SELECT 
cast([BINARY_VALUE] as varchar(max)) BLOB_VALUE 
FROM [PROD3].[DOMAIN].[BLOBS]
WHERE OBJECT_ID = 881462
```

How can I save the whole of my converted binary data to a file using sqlserver?

Comment: how much big is the output

Answer (score 1):

did you try bcp command? It should work fine.

Comment: Um ... no ... I don't know about BCP - is it built in already ??

Comment: This is a case sensitive command which comes with SQL Server. If you are using windows authentication then you'll be fine with -T switch: Here is an example.  c:\>bcp "<SQL Query>" queryout c:\temp\data.txt -c -T -S SQLSERVERNAME

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question :

[varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server)

TL;DR: You should not use CAST, but CONVERT :

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(max), BINARY_VALUE,2) as BLOB_VALUE 
FROM [PROD3].[DOMAIN].[BLOBS]
WHERE OBJECT_ID = 881462
```

Note the use of the style parameter 2.

Comment: SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), [BINARY_VALUE],2) as BLOB_VALUE 
FROM [PROD3].[DOMAIN].[BLOBS]
WHERE OBJECT_ID = 881462

Above worked but DID NOT convert to readable string !!??

Comment: Try converting to NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR : `SELECT 
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), BINARY_VALUE,2) as BLOB_VALUE 
FROM [PROD3].[DOMAIN].[BLOBS]
WHERE OBJECT_ID = 881462`

Comment: Nah... same result. CASTworks, CONVERT doesn't seem to,

Comment: Yes! Thanks! NVARCHAR did it!