# Convert varbinary to string in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to display one table format report using ssrs.
In my data set one column data type is var-binary.
How to convert this var-binary datatype to string using expressions?

Comment: Did you try any of the conversion functions in SSRS? Example, Cstr()?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), varbinary_value, 2);
```

As per [varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you for your Response snowlock.But how can i use this conversion in expressions(fx) to display this field in ssrs report.

Comment: Convert it in sql and pass it through as Varchar.

Comment: Thank you Snowlockk but i have restriction to convert this in sqlserver side.I have to do this conversion in reporting side.