# SQL Server convert from varbinary to varchar

Tags: sql-server

I have been banging my head against a wall on this. I am trying to get data from a field in a SQL Server database that has a type of `varbinary(28)`.

I just can't work out how to convert the data from hex back to chars.

I know that a column = '1081X' and the hex stored in the database is `0x7E959C9ABB818C`.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    0x7E959C9ABB818C, '1081X',
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(28), '1081X'),
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(28), N'1081X')

-- 0x7E959C9ABB818C 1081X   0x3130383158    0x31003000380031005800
```

Any ideas on how to retrieve '1081X' from the code 0x7E959C9ABB818C ?

Comment: Just to make sure I give you the right solution, the value in the binary field is ASCII text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server)

Comment: @virusstorm i think so. i have tried UTF and ASCII but cant work it out.

Comment: Start over. Exactly **how** do you know that this column contains the text value you provided?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to integrate with a vendor database.  The row has information on a drug including its name in text.  For that drug i can look up the PBS code for that drug, which is 1081X

Answer (score 1):

I get different results.

Are you sure the value `0x7E959C9ABB818C` should translate to: `'1081X'`

```
--what OP appears to be asking:
select cast(0x7E959C9ABB818C as varchar(max))  --result: ~•œš»Œ

--what does cast of OP question provide?
select cast('1081X' as varbinary(max))   --result: 0x3130383158

--test cast back
select cast(0x3130383158 as varchar(max))  --result: 1081X
```

Comment: Yes, i am trying to integrate with a vendor database.  The row has information on a drug including its name in text.  For that drug i can look up the PBS code for that drug, which is 1081X

Comment: @pgee70 I got the same result as Brien. I don't think the binary value you are working with is what you think it is.

Comment: @pgee70 Hello again, I am coming back to this.. curious did you ever figure out what the problem/solution was? If so, maybe post it as an Answer and accept your own answer?