# How can I select convert a VARBINARY column (containing a text file) to an actual text string?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a `VARBINARY` column, which contains values like these:

`0x500073007900630068006F006C006F0067006900630061006C00200053007400720061007400...`

These values represent HTML files.

I'm trying to figure out how to `SELECT` these values as HTML strings.

I tried selecting `CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Content, 2) AS ContentConverted` – but that just gave me the same value with the 0x prefix removed:

`500073007900630068006F006C006F0067006900630061006C00200053007400720061007400...`

I also tried `CAST(Content AS VARCHAR(max)) AS ContentConverted` – but that (bizarrely) just gives me a single letter:

`P`

Lastly, I tried this hack:

`CAST(CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><![CDATA[',Content,']]>') AS XML).value('.','nvarchar(max)')`

...and that just produces an "illegal xml character" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: _but that (bizarrely) just gives me a single letter_ Why is that bizarre? As ascii, the second tuple 0x00 is the string terminator. The first tuple is 0x50 which is the letter P. So it seems you have unicode characters and you should be able to "see" the string by casting to [unicode](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09906f06b5163aff4c3ff652dc29eab3).

Comment: @SMor: casting to NVARCHAR did the trick! Thanks. I'm new to SQL Server, so I didn't understand the difference between VARCHAR and NVARCHAR. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll flag it as the best answer.

Comment: @TravisMiller, `nvarchar` is Unicode. The binary value in your question is 2-bytes per character (UTF-2 Unicide encoding).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [varbinary to string on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289988/varbinary-to-string-on-sql-server)